# broken pipe socket exception (errno=32) on Google Cloud Run and Dart vm

Tags: http, authentication, dart, google-cloud-run

Now in late March 2021, my authentication always works correctly on my linux (popOS) laptop and always fails on GCR.

```
  import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth_io.dart' as auth;
  import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    
  static Future<String> authAsync(final String jsonFilenamePath) {
    //
    final client = http.Client();

    return _getPrivateKeyAsync(jsonFilenamePath)
        .then((pk) => _buildJson(pk))
        .then((jason) => auth.ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson(jason))
        // the next line will throw a broken pipe socket exception on GCR, but will run fine on my ubuntu laptop.
        .then((saCreds) => auth.obtainAccessCredentialsViaServiceAccount(saCreds, scopes, client), onError: _printErr)
        .whenComplete(() => client.close())
        .then((accessCredentials) => accessCredentials.accessToken.data);
  }
```

That method is more async/non-blocking so I tested another authentication method that was more of a synchronous/blocking style.  Both fail for the same error on GCR.  Both work great on my laptop every time I run it.

part of my pubspec.yaml...

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.9.0 <3.0.0' 
dependencies:
  googleapis_auth: ^1.1.0 
  http: ^0.13.1
```

The error on GCR...

> Asynchroous error
> SocketException: OS Error: Broken pipe, errno = 32, address = accounts.google.com, port = 57210

My GCR docker file ...

```
FROM google/dart-runtime
ENV PORT 8080
```

It's strange because the authentication was working really well on GCR in early February 2021 but then it started to fail on GCR in mid-March 2021.

This looks like a C++ networking error to me.  How might I learn more about this problem or test solutions to resolve it?

It is not lost on me that I am using a front-end language, built for responsive UI, as a server-side/middleware tool.  I was hoping Dart would be great for full-stack development, like js on node or deno.

I just found some other stats from GCR and docker.  GCR says it is running linux 4.4.0 from January 10 2016.  My laptop is running linux 5.11.0.

Comment: Hi there, can you include the code between the `client` and the `then` clause? In the next comment I will include my code which did not generate the message 32. Also what is the number of request that end up with message 32? is it all of them, only the first ones after deployment?

Comment: `var client = http.Client();
    obtainAccessCredentialsViaServiceAccount(accountCredentials, scopes, client)
    .then((AccessCredentials credentials) {
      var tmp = credentials.toJson();
      print('$tmp');
      // Access credentials are available in [credentials].
      client.close();`

Comment: i updated the top code sample.  All requests on GCR will error with a broken pipe socket exception; not just the first attempt after deployment.

Comment: Have you printed and compared the variables `saCreds`, `scopes` & `, client` locally and in cloud run? Also the type of variable. How do you process the credentials.json file? do you upload it to cloud run by sending it in the request? or do you pull from cloud storage?

Comment: I have not printed and compared the vars yet but I will soon.  I ship the creds.json file with the deployed build, using the gcloud cli.

Comment: Yes, I'm now printing saCreds, scopes, and client to the gcr logs and I'm getting expected values for those.

Comment: Can you please follow the instructions on this github repo and let me know if the CR service sends the 32 message? https://github.com/Rookie24601/dartShare
If you do not receive an error message, can you please provide a github repo with a reproducible code to obtain the 32 message?